# Ambiguous between syntax and semantic error

Tags: grammar, semantics

For C/C++ lang, there is a constraint that every element in an array must have the same type. So if we initialize an array with many types of elements, an error occurs. Is this error syntax/grammar or semantic one?

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages, please also see the tags' descriptions that you applied. In any case, see the C++ standard (or, e.g. cppreference.com) for the distinction (if any) between the two error classes.

Comment: @Duy Duy It is a semantic error. For example a narrowing conversion of an initializer in C++.

Comment: `int a [] = {c,d,e,f};` is syntactically and grammatically correct.

Comment: *"an error occurs"* - That says nothing. What error?

Comment: Neither language standard defines "syntax error" or "semantic error".

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: C++ in particular has entirely different rules about initialization than C, if only for constructors. The second claim ( "if we initialize an array with many types, an error occurs") is just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the C lexical analysis or grammar distinguishes `int` from `void`. The both appear exactly once in the C grammar, as a *type-specifier* in C 6.7.2 1. Therefore, the only way to distinguish these two samples of code:

```
void *x[] = { (char *) 0 };
```

and

```
int *x[] = { (char *) 0 };
```

is by using the meaning of the code, as given by the C standard in constraints and other text. They are in fact distinguished by compilers, as the first is accepted without complaint about the types, but the second results in a complaint about the type of the initializer for the array element. Therefore, this is a semantic error.